# Please explain this sql query what its doing

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, t-sql

I have this sql query got generated by linqpad, its working fine but I am not getting how?

> Linq statement

```
Documents.GroupBy(p => new { p.PatientId, p.DocumentType })
                    .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(p => 
p.CreationDateTime).FirstOrDefault().DocumentId)
```

> sql query

```
SELECT (
    SELECT [t3].[DocumentId]
    FROM (
        SELECT TOP (1) [t2].[DocumentId]
        FROM [Document] AS [t2]
        WHERE ([t1].[PatientId] = [t2].[PatientId]) AND ([t1].[DocumentType] = [t2].[DocumentType])
        ORDER BY [t2].[CreationDateTime] DESC
        ) AS [t3]
    ) AS [value]
FROM (
    SELECT [t0].[PatientId], [t0].[DocumentType]
    FROM [Document] AS [t0]
    GROUP BY [t0].[PatientId], [t0].[DocumentType]
    ) AS [t1]
```

Comment: It is fetching most recent document ID for each document type of each patient

Comment: Rather than asking us what it does, you should be asking us about what you don't understand in the query. Knowing what a query does, and knowing how the query does what it does are very different. What about the statement above don't you understand?

Comment: In SQL 
If a patient have multiple doc of a documenttype then how its grouping them by PatientId and DocumentType and get latest doc??

Comment: the generated SQL obviously is not optimal. The general idea is: Fetch all distinct patientid and document type, and for each of those gather all documents, order them by creation time descending and return the first one's document id. Essentially the upper block is the sub query, the lower block the "loop".

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Without seeing the query execution plan of the SQL engine, it is premature to say how optimal the query is.